# Displaying complete context menu in windows 7 library folders

Tags: windows-7, contextmenu, special-folders

When browsing non-special/standard folders in explorer (windows 7), I have various custom right-click context menu options such as:

- "Open command window here" (shift+ rightclick)
- TortoiseHG
- WinMerge
- *...etc...*

The problem is that these options do not come up in the context menu when navigating library folders *(such as Documents/My Documents)*, and instead a 'blank'/clean version of the context menu without any 3rd party/custom extensions is shown.

This is quite annoying, considering I work a lot with command prompt and like to use source control on most of my documents. Only when you navigate via a libraries link does the context menu lose extra options (i.e. you still get the options if you navigate to the special folder location without going through any library shortcut)

My current workaround is that I have manually navigated to the documents folder, and added that to favourites in explorer, using the favourites link instead of the library link.

Is there any solution to this mysterious library folder limited context menu behaviour? I've tried searching, but could not find a way to lift this limitation.

Comment: Per-folder solution:  

1. Right click on shortcut to folder  

2. In target box, move to end and append 2x double quote - ""  

3. Target should now be   


    <original target> ""  

Voila, library functionality is disabled. Thanks google: http://www.askvg.com/windows-explorer-always-opens-in-libraries-view-in-windows-7-how-to-change-target-folder/

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple context menu1.0 from http://www.brothersoft.com/simple-context-menu-438026.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just found the answer to this.

If you select a specific folder within the library, and right-click that one while holding shift, it should work as expected. Works for me anyway.

The given reason was that Library maps to two different folders.

Answer (score 0):

This likely belongs on SuperUser.com, but it should be automagically moved.

From what it sounds like, I bet the issue is that a library folder isn't really a folder, it's just a logical mechanism, so the context menu isn't going to be the same as that of a folder (because the same options may not work directly).